# Wordpress multisite share login cookies

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

i have issue with login.
in my config file i set following:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'example.com');
define('COOKIEHASH', md5('example.com'));
```

we use sso for login so in the code we have following:

```
$user_data = get_user_by( 'email', 'email from sso response');
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, true, true);
wp_safe_redirect(get_bloginfo( 'url' ));
```

i see on redirect that cookies are being set but then deleted.

```
set-cookie: wordpress_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/wp-admin; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/wp-admin; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpress_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/wp-content/plugins; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/wp-content/plugins; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpress_logged_in_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpress_logged_in_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wp-settings-0=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wp-settings-time-0=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wordpress_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpress_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpressuser_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpresspass_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpressuser_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpresspass_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wp-postpass_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=+; expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2020 07:06:16 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/wp-content/plugins; domain=eaxample.com; secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/wp-admin; domain=eaxample.com; secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: wordpress_logged_in_5c17a572de52dec9e57184ab4ca0b7ae=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=eaxample.com; secure; HttpOnly
```

from what i see this function sets cookie but they are already expired.

Answer (score 0):

I literally fixed this issue yesterday. Try adding the function below to your wp_config.

`define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', false);`

Note: looks like you are already calling this function, so if that doesn't work. Comment the one you listed above.

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'example.com');
```